# Falha ao criar campo no SimpleDataSet no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Tenho um SimpleDataSet que já tinha registros de um banco de dados.
Eu adicionei um campo para funcionar em memória.
Quando eu clico com o botão direito não aparece a opção Create DataSet e quando eu copilo o projeto da erro: SimpleDataset Field 'CNS' not found conforme print.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: esse seu Field CNS pode estar vinculado a algum DBEdit de algum formulário e também pode ser por não ter o CNS na tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe.
Eu estava criando para guardar dados em memória.
Resolvido ao colocar fieldCalculate.